# Custom printing functions with sympy

Tags: sympy

I would like to do some math with sympy. However, working with functions gives a very messy output.

Take the example of the chain rule.

```
import sympy as sym
def ddt (s):
    return sym.diff(s, t)
x, y, z, t = sym.symbols("x y z t")
a = sym.Function('a')(x,y,z,t)
b = sym.Function('b')(x,y,z,t)

c = sym.Function('c')(a, b)
print (ddt(c))
```

This prints all the dependencies of the variables:

```
Derivative(a(x, y, z, t), t)*Derivative(c(a(x, y, z, t), b(x, y, z, t)), a(x, y, z, t)) + Derivative(b(x, y, z, t), t)*Derivative(c(a(x, y, z, t), b(x, y, z, t)), b(x, y, z, t))
```

Anyway of removing the dependencies? (x,y,z,t) do not appear in the output:
And get something like:

```
Derivative(a, t)*Derivative(c, a) + Derivative(b, t)*Derivative(c, b)
```

[https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.image?\frac{\partial&space;a}{\partial&space;t}\frac{\partial&space;c}{\partial&space;a}&space;+&space;\frac{\partial&space;b}{\partial&space;t}\frac{\partial&space;c}{\partial&space;b}&space;](https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.image?%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpartial&space;a%7D%7B%5Cpartial&space;t%7D%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpartial&space;c%7D%7B%5Cpartial&space;a%7D&space;+&space;%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpartial&space;b%7D%7B%5Cpartial&space;t%7D%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpartial&space;c%7D%7B%5Cpartial&space;b%7D&space;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom printer, which quickly become a tedious job. A basic implementation is this:

```py
from sympy.printing import StrPrinter
from sympy.core.function import AppliedUndef

class MyStrPrinterPrinter(StrPrinter):
    """ Extended Latex printer with new options:
    1. applied_no_args=False: wheter applied undefined function should be
        rendered with their arguments. Default to False.
    """
    def __init__(self, settings=None):
        self._default_settings.update({
                "applied_no_args": False,
            }
        )
        super().__init__(settings)
    def _print_Function(self, expr):
        if isinstance(expr, AppliedUndef) and self._settings["applied_no_args"]:
            return expr.func.__name__
        return super()._print_Function(expr)

def my_str(expr, **settings):
    return MyStrPrinterPrinter(settings).doprint(expr)

def myprint(expr):
    print(my_str(expr, applied_no_args=True))
```

Then, on your code:

```py
import sympy as sym
sym.init_printing(
def ddt (s):
    return sym.diff(s, t)
x, y, z, t = sym.symbols("x y z t")
a = sym.Function('a')(x,y,z,t)
b = sym.Function('b')(x,y,z,t)

c = sym.Function('c')(a, b)
myprint(ddt(c))
# out: Derivative(a, t)*Derivative(c, a) + Derivative(b, t)*Derivative(c, b)
```

Theoretically, you could execute this line of code at the beginning of your code block, and then it should use the new printer:

```
sym.init_printing(str_printer=my_str)
```

Unfortunately, I'm unable to get it working on Jupyter. That's why I created the `myprint` function.